# Name Collision In Wsimport Generated Class And My Original Web Service Class

Tags: java, web-services, class, duplicates, wsimport

I have a simple web service class defined as follows:

```
package com.me.basiccalcws;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class Calculator {
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

I use the *wsgen* tool to generate a *wsdl*:

```
wsgen -classpath ..\bin -wsdl -s src -r wsdl -d bin com.me.basiccalcws.Calculator
```

Then I use *wsimport* to generate client stubs:

```
wsimport -s src ..\_wsgen\wsdl\CalculatorService.wsdl
```

The files that are generated after running *wsimport* are as follows:

```
Add.java
AddResponse.java
Calculator.java
CalculatorService.java
ObjectFactory.java
package-info.java
```

and all these files have the same namespace as my original web service class (com.me.basiccalcws).

When I import these files into my Eclipse project there is a name collision. My original class name was Calculator and yet the *wsimport* tool created another class called Calculator in the same namespace.

How do I prevent this namespace/name collision (or is it intentional)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing you can do is provide the `targetNamespace` in the `javax.jws.WebService` annotation, something like that.

```
package com.me.basiccalcws;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://client.basiccalcws.me.com/")
public class Calculator {
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

If you dont provide the `-p` option in the [`wsimport`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html), this `targetNamespace` is the destiny package.