# how to work wsimport for this WSDL i get errors and i cant make it work

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, wsimport

i am trying to use the command wsimport to get the java classes for a SOAP Service, but i get lots of errors.

The Url WSDL is this 
https://onlineavl2api-mx.navmanwireless.com/onlineavl/api/V1.3/service.asmx?WSDL

and this is one of the errors i get(there is a bunch)

```
 [ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 820 of https://onlineavl2api-mx.navmanwireless.com/onlineavl/api/V1.3/ser
  vice.asmx?WSDL
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate WebService Clients i use:

wsimport -keep -p clientC  https://onlineavl2api-mx.navmanwireless.com/onlineavl/api/V1.3/service.asmx?WSDL

Comment: did you try and run it? i couldn't

Answer (score 0):

wsimport is trying to generate classes in the same package with same name, to fix this I would try:

1.- ommit -p clientC

or

2.-  Add an annotation on the webservice like this:

```
package com.me.basiccalcws;

import javax.jws.WebService;

    @WebService(targetNamespace = "http://client.basiccalcws.me.com/")
    public class Calculator {
        public int add(int a, int b) {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
```

took from [Name Collision In Wsimport Generated Class And My Original Web Service Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405176/name-collision-in-wsimport-generated-class-and-my-original-web-service-class)

Best Regards

Comment: i get the same by ommiting the -p clientC, so how exactly do i add taht to the webservice?

Comment: let me know if it was of some help

Comment: i think it is of help, the problem is that im unsure on how to do this, where do i put that code??

Comment: the code as it is should be placed in a package named com.me.basiccalcws and define a class named Calculator there you have to put the code.Once you have done that you have already created the service and can execute de wsimport on that service, you have to do something similar for your own web service. For the webservice you are creating the client do you have control over that code or  you are only creating a client to a service that doesn't belong to you?

Comment: im creating a client to a service that doesn't belong to me, and for some reason wsimport wont work on it.

Comment: eres de mexico segun veo, yo tambien, pudiste correrlo? aun sigo sin poder

Comment: Ya no tuve oportunidad ayer pero mañana lo pruebo y te aviso que onda

Comment: muchas gracias, seria de gran ayuda

Comment: No se pudo compañero? nadie me a podido dar solución ni en otros foros :\

Comment: hola, ya no supe nada de ti, no se pudo de la manera que me comentaste??